# Auto-formatting RestAssured test cases in my IDE

Tags: automated-testing

We have our tests implemented in RestAssured, using nice and readable convention of indentation for given/when/then parts.

```
given().
  param("key1", "value1").
  param("key2", "value2").
when().
  post("/somewhere").
then().
  body(containsString("OK"));
```

However, when I apply automatic formatting with template (Google code style for Java) in Intellij IDEA, the formatting I had gets destroyed.

```
given().
        param("key1", "value1").
        param("key2", "value2").
        when().
        post("/somewhere").
        then().
        body(containsString("OK"));
```

Is there a way my IDE or maven formats RestAssured statements with expected indentations, while the rest keeps with respect to the Google template? Or at least, it doesn't destroy what I have set for RestAssured statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution I found so far it to turn off formatting for certain sections, so that IDE does not destroy that.

**In Intellij**

1. Surround the code fragment with

   ```
   // @formatter:off
   ...
   // @formatter:on
   ```
2. Preferences -> Code Style -> General -> Formatter Control -> Enable formatter markers in comments

[image]

This does not auto-format RestAssured section, but at least does not destroy it.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? Maybe modifying the ide's schema?

Comment: @Dan What is IDE's schema?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "scheme." From the screenshot you provided you can import a code style scheme. Is it possible to create a scheme that will skip the autoformatting?

Comment: @Dan I haven't found such a schema.

Comment: `Editor -> Code Style -> Formatter tab -> Do not format: [<test files pattern>]`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like disable formatting approach, but I did something like this, not awesome but little bit readable (added empty line)

```
given()
        .param("x", "y")
        .header("z", "p")

        .when()
        .get("something")

        .then()
        .statusCode(200);
```